# How to load referenced document in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a MongoDB collection called `categories` which has a self-reference(`parent`) like follows.

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Category', schema);
```

When i query it just returns the object id of the referenced document.

```
{
    "_id": "63731fe1ce1bf2f534f9307e",
    "name": "Glass cleaners",
    "parent": "63731fbbce1bf2f534f9307d",
}
```

I want to load the document referenced by `parent`, so i used following code to load the parent seperatly.

```
let parentCat = await Category.findOne({ _id: category.parent });
```

Is there an easy way of doing this because above is bit difficult to maintain if in my opinion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query population in mongoose instead of querying parent again.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

You have to call `populate()` when you query which will load parent document.

```
 Category.find().populate('parent');
```

Highly suggest you to go through the mongoose documentation.

Comment: Yes, so the final query will look like this. await Category.findOne({_id: categoryId }).populate('parent')

Comment: Thanks for the fast response guys. This works as expected.